# How to expose the distinct filter in views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

i was wondering if there by any chance is possible to implement an exposed filter in views that either sets the SELECT DISCTINCT() on or off. Does anyone know if that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible, because distinct is not a filter but a setting on the root of the view you are creating.

Comment: Ah, thanks anyways. I solved it by creating two different views and used the views tab display with ajax and managed to created a sort of checkbox filter :)